# Android app terminates when calling data to a ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to call data to a Listview, but app terminates.

in the databasehelper.java i have this function:

```
public List<Presentation> getAllPresentations() {
    List<Presentation> presentations = new ArrayList<Presentation>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRESENTATION;
    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Presentation p = new Presentation();
            p.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
            p.setTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE)));
            p.setDescription(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESCRIPTION)));
            p.setPatient_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PATIENT_NAME)));

            presentations.add(p);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return presentations;
}
```

in the xml file (view_presentation) i have a ListView with the id list

in the view_presentations.java i have this code:

```
public class view_presentations extends Activity
{
    // Database Helper
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_presentation);

        if (db.getPresentationsCount() != 0)
        {
            List<Presentation> list = db.getAllPresentations();
            ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Presentation>(this, R.layout.view_presentation, list));

        }
    }
}
```

in this point should display the list with all presentations, but the app terminates. Any help?

Comment: "the app terminates" by black magic? or maybe you get a descriptive stack trace detailing the problem?

Comment: @rupps nothing gets displayed, only the query of the data.

Comment: are you sure? have you checked logcat? and btw, where do you initialize **db**?

Comment: initialize 'DatabaseHelper db'  before using it.

Comment: @rupps sometimes it gives me a NullPointException.

Comment: @shijil I have inicialised it,

Comment: you need something like db=new databasehelper() before using db :)